# Deep copy a graph structure in Go

Tags: go, data-structures

I have some pretty classic looking nodes:

```
type MyNode struct {
    value string
    edges []*MyNode
}
```

I use these nodes to build a graph.  When I build this graph, I make connections both ways between nodes with a function:

```
func (node *MyNode) ConnectTo(otherNode *MyNode) *MyNode {
    node.edges = append(node.edges, othernode)
    otherNode.edges = append(otherNode.edges, node)
    return otherNode
}
```

I want to make an isomorphism of the graph, so I can perform operations on it and return it as it's own set of nodes.  A simple copy constructor, or a copy() or even normal deep copy methods won't retain the connection structure.

Do I have to go through the pains of making a map between the new structure and the old?  Or is there some sort of pretty Go way to do this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you have tried and didn't work? This question is fairly broad and will likely be hard to answer without some more specific details.

Comment: "Is there some sort of pretty way to do this in Go" I think is the question here.  An isomorphism of a graph means that it retains the same connection structure as the source graph.  In trying to put together a way of doing this, I stopped short after making a deep copy and realizing the edge connections are to the source graph rather than the new one.  If that's still not clear please let me know, I feel the question is fairly direct.

Comment: If there's not a direct and concise way of doing it, that's a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: There very likely may not be a very concise method if implementing this. In general go does not prioritize clever solutions. I suspect to achieve this you will just have to write several loops that reconstruct the graph in its modified form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is not a magic way to create an isomorphism of a graph in Go.

One of the principle Go builtin functions and language features follows is that they do not hide complexity, in terms of both time and space. Creating an isomorphism is beyond that scope.

The idea of using a map is the right approach, and I wouldn't call it a pain. A few lines of code can get it done.